# Histogram of integer values with correct x-axis ticks and labels

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

I have integer values from `0` to `n` (included) and I would like to plot a histogram with `n+1` bars at with the correct x-axis labels. Here is my attempt.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate integer values
n = 20
values = np.random.randint(low=0, high=(n+1), size=1000)

# Plot histogram
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 4))
_, bins, _ = ax.hist(values, bins=n+1, edgecolor='k', color='lightsalmon')
ax.set_xticks(bins)
ax.set_xticklabels(bins.astype(int))
plt.show()
```

It is almost correct, but the x-axis looks weird.

[image]

Comment: I figured out that I could actually create bins using `bins=np.arange(start=-0.5, stop=(n+1), step=1.0)` but then the ticks are still wrong

Comment: Ah! I could then set the x-ticks to `np.arange(n+1)`.

Comment: You could also try Seaborn, e.g. `sns.histplot(values, discrete=True, ax=ax)`. See https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate integer values
n = 20
values = np.random.randint(low=0, high=(n+1), size=1000)

# Plot histogram
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 4))
bins = np.arange(start=-0.5, stop=(n+1), step=1)
_ = ax.hist(values, bins=bins, edgecolor='k', color='lightsalmon')
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(n+1)
plt.show()
```